# Swift Date Picker date

Tags: ios, macos, swift

How can I make something happen in a specific hour in the Date Picker?

I am just learning Swift I would appreciate any orientation. Thank you!

I can grab the time the user select when he click a button, but how can I make something happen when we arrive to that time and the app is active?

(I am not looking for localNotifications, I want something happen WHEN THAT APP IS ACTIVE)

I put this inside ViewController.swift > class ViewControler: UIViewController:

```
    let now = NSDate()

    @IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
        // grab the selected date from the date picker
        let wakeUpTime = datePicker.date
    }
```

Comment: This is too broad. You have to be more specific. You can use an `NSTimer`, `UILocalNotification` or a remote notification, among other things, to "make something happen".

Comment: you have to use notification pattern for your problem http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns

Comment: @Leo: sorry I am new and I do not know where to begin. I would like to have an alert when now = wakeUpTime. What is the first step?

Comment: If you want an alert, why have you ruled out a local notification? It is very convenient for your purpose. If you only wish to have the notification fire off when the app is in the foreground, you can leave the sound and message empty (`nil`) and it will only call the app delegate without actually displaying anything if the app is in the background.

Comment: Another option is to calculate the difference between target date and the current date, and set a `NSTimer` to tick at that date. This is not fun to manage if app goes to background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something to happen when the app is active, do the following:

1. Grab the user-selected date from the picker. Save it to user
   defaults.
2. Calculate the number of seconds from now until the user-specified
   date:

   ```
   let seconds = userDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate() - 
     NSDate().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
   ```
3. Create a one-shot timer that fires in that many seconds.

Done.

If you want your app to work correctly if the user switches your app to the background and then back, kill the timer on the way to the background.

When you get launched or return to the foreground, read the saved date, and repeat the above. (After checking to see if the saved date has already passed.)

Comment: It sounds good, thank you!. I am working on that direction. There is a small typo problem that gives an error, I think it should be: timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate

Comment: Yes, I did have a typo in my answer.